# How to create a Dynamic upload path Django

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest api that converts user uploaded video to frame using Opencv.

I also have a function `upload_to` that creates a dynamic path for the uploaded video.

I want to write the frames from the video into the upload_to folder.

I tried `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(upload_to,'new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)` but it yield an error.

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone.now()
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename.lower())
    return f"SmatCrow/{instance.name}/{now:%Y-%m-%d}{extension}"
```

Opencv script

```
def video_to_frame(video):
    now = timezone.now()
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    i=1
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        if i%10 == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(('media/SmatCrow/new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)
        i+=1
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My model.py

```
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyVideo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) 
        tfile.write(self.videofile.read())
        vid = video_to_frame((tfile.name))
```

Comment: What about `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(upload_to(),'new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)` - so calling `upload_to()` in order to get the result? This might nor work as the time stmp will not be the same each time so you ned to call path = upload_to() just once before the function call and pass the path variable instead.

Comment: @jlapoutre the `upload_to` function requires a parameter and also the path variable comes form the fields in the model like  `instance.name`. 
the user who uploads a video provide a `name` field for the model. so I can't hardcode the `name` field as a path when it has not yet been provided by a user

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of this situation where I was saving different company bardode by creating separate directory what is did I defined *MEDIA_ROOT* and override save method in the model
and by getting the company name through api call checked for different company and creates seperated folders

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        if field.name == 'barcode':
            field.upload_to = f'{self.company.name}/{str(date.today())}'
   
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs), self.company.name
```

Comment: The video get uploaded to the right folder. I want the frame I generated using opencv to be in the same folder with the video.